# How to communicate with a raspberry pi cube satellite?

Tags: gpio, radio, gnuradio

I am planning to build a cube satellite that will be above 150km - 600km altitude in the LEO(Lower earth orbit).

What can i use to communicate with it. How would that work? I know I will need a radio transceiver. But I will need to know which ones are compatible with a raspi. Any open source code available for it etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most transceivers are proprietary, so I'm not really sure if [CubeSat modules (link)](http://www.syrlinks.com/en/products/cubesat-and-nanosatellite-platforms.html) are compatible with a Pi. They might help you out if you buy one.

I suggest using another platform other than a Pi. I'm not sure if it's fit for orbiting at that height unprotected. Also, its components aren't really rated for radiation. ECC memory would also be a plus.

If you insist, you can probably use [PiTX (link)](http://www.rtl-sdr.com/transmitting-fm-am-ssb-sstv-and-fsq-with-just-a-raspberry-pi/) and a radio amplifier setup. Receiving signals are also another matter since PiTX only transmits.

Comment: Hi @pandalion98 - Thanks for the heads up. If not a Pi, what would you suggest? (atleast i read that Pi's have been cused in a cubesat recently) Also, I will try to get in touch with Syrlinks to know if an integration is possible.

Comment: @RiteshKsheersagar Not sure. If the Pi is good enough for NASA, I think it would be good enough for you. I'm not making any guarantees though.

Comment: @RiteshKsheersagar UPDATE: You might want to see this: http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20150023353.pdf. Don't forget to give me some access. I would love to take a selfie from space :)

Comment: This is like just what i wanted. I will do some more research on the same. I will surely give you some access :) . Still a long way to go though...just getting started with the Pi now. Many hurdles going to come our way..but with some good support form the community like you guys, I think its surely achievable.

Comment: @RiteshKsheersagar http://space.stackexchange.com/q/15099/11846